# Can i use WMI queries against my application for getting a custom data?

Tags: c#, wmi-query

I have an application that complicated with server and clients..
Is there  a option to using WMI queries for getting a data from my server?

I see that can using against performance counters, but the performance counters return numeric values, and i need to return a string values..

Is  there an option for to do it?

Comment: what sort of 'string' value are you expecting? Can't you just convert the numeric value into string? e.g. .NET's Convert.ToString(value) method?

Comment: for an example if i using wmi queries against the server i want to getting the current datetime (just example...), how to can i to do it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394590(VS.85).aspx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323613/time-of-another-machine, both these link have information that can help you get started. if you still struggle then post the code you have done and i'm sure people will be more than willing to help. The code in the first link is VB but it can easily be converted to c#.

Comment: first of all, thanks, my question is different, i asked how by using WMI queries i can to getting a data from app or server? maybe i don't explain clearly? other example, i have a little application - that always tick every second and display the current datetime, and other application that send wmi query to first app and ask for data (datetime)?