# Client Machine Local Time

Tags: c#, datetime

DateTime.Now() is returning server time where application is running on server. I need a way to find Client Machine Time in a Class File in C# without using JavaScript.

Please suggest if there is any workaround for this request.

Comment: you can try and look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323613/time-of-another-machine)

Comment: "Without using JavaScript" suggests you're talking about a web application. In which case, you are going to need to run *some* code on the client machine that communicates the time. You can't run arbitrary C# code on the client machine, so JS is pretty much your only choice.

Comment: I believe you cannot do that since the codebehind is executed in the server. I thin the only way is to get it using client side script.

Comment: You could also use the `Date` request header.